# Lean: Prove that if homomorphisms are equal as functions, then they are equal as homomorphisms.

Tags: type-theory, theorem-provers

Let's say I have a simple magma structure defined as follows:

```
structure Magma :=
  (carrier : Type u)
  (op : carrier → carrier → carrier)
```

together with a magma homomorphism structure:

```
class hom {X Y : Magma} (f : X → Y) :=
  (resp_op : ∀ x y : X,
    f (X.op x y) = Y.op (f x) (f y) )

structure Hom (X Y : Magma) :=
  (func : X → Y) (hom_func : hom func)
```

And I need to prove the following (trivial) lemma:

```
lemma equate_hom {X Y : Magma} :
∀ f g : Hom X Y, f.func = g.func  →  f = g
```

I have been stuck on this for some time now. But there must be some really simple way to do this, right? The full example is [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=universe%20u%0A%0A%2F-%0Amagmas%3A%0A-%2F%0A%0Astructure%20Magma%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%28carrier%20%3A%20Type%20u%29%0A%20%20%28op%20%3A%20carrier%20%E2%86%92%20carrier%20%E2%86%92%20carrier%29%0A%0Ainstance%20Magma_to_sort%20%3A%0Ahas_coe_to_sort%20Magma%20%28Type%20u%29%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%E2%9F%A8%20Magma.carrier%20%E2%9F%A9%0A%0A%2F-%0Ahomomorphisms%3A%0A-%2F%0A%0Aclass%20hom%20%7BX%20Y%20%3A%20Magma%7D%20%28f%20%3A%20X%20%E2%86%92%20Y%29%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%28resp_op%20%3A%20%E2%88%80%20x%20y%20%3A%20X%2C%0A%20%20%20%20f%20%28X.op%20x%20y%29%20%3D%20Y.op%20%28f%20x%29%20%28f%20y%29%20%29%0A%0Astructure%20Hom%20%28X%20Y%20%3A%20Magma%29%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%28func%20%3A%20X%20%E2%86%92%20Y%29%20%28hom_func%20%3A%20hom%20func%29%0A%0Ainstance%20Hom.to_fun%20%7BX%20Y%20%3A%20Magma%7D%20%3A%0Ahas_coe_to_fun%20%28Hom%20X%20Y%29%20%28%CE%BB%20_%2C%20X%20%E2%86%92%20Y%29%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20%E2%9F%A8%20Hom.func%20%E2%9F%A9%0A%0A--%20how%20do%20I%20prove%20this%3F%0Alemma%20equate_hom%20%7BX%20Y%20%3A%20Magma%7D%20%3A%0A%E2%88%80%20f%20g%20%3A%20Hom%20X%20Y%2C%20f.func%20%3D%20g.func%20%20%E2%86%92%20%20f%20%3D%20g%20%3A%3D%0A%20%20sorry).

Comment: I don't know Lean and may be totally up the wrong tree but it seems to me that this needs to be an axiom and not a lemma.

Comment: Yeah, how is $f=g$ defined if not as `f.func=g.func`?

Comment: Started with Lean yesterday, but I suspect that it needs both `f.func = g.func` and `f.hom_func = g.hom_func` and maybe it doesn't recognise that `f.hom_func` and `g.hom_func` are of the same type?

Comment: I think you can prove `f.hom_func = g.hom_func` by `rfl` easily. But then I still don't know how to combine the two to obtain the result.